# Can't I make apps running on Android TV with overlay?

Tags: android, overlay, android-tv

I'm trying to Dump Audio while playing media on my Android TV. I tried to Dump by creating an app. But when I run the app, no matter how much I modify the layout of Activity, the media stops playing and the activity of the launched app covers the screen.

I was wondering can't make an overlay app on Android TV. And can make it, I'd be so grateful if you could let me know a reference adout overlay.